# How to make my Realtime database readable only by my users?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using the Firebase Realtime database only to know if I still have a connection to it like suggester [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). So, there is nothing in it.

I thought the rules that I put was enough, but Google thinks it is not safe and I need to change it.

So, I went from:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

That worked fine for my iOS app, but not with my Android app. Putting the 'read' to 'false' makes that solution not workable because of the solution suggested [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#limitations).

What would you suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that had the same issue, here what Google tech support suggested me

> You could modify this a bit like FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(“connect/” + (new Date()).toString()).keepSynced()

> And in your Realtime Database rules, allow to read, write auth != null to this “connect” child.

It would look like this:

```
{

  "rules": {
    "connect":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    ".write": false,
    ".read": false
  }
}
```